# Potential Method For Decimal Counter

Tags: amortized-analysis

There is a counter that counts the number of items in the store. For every increase in item or item that has been inserted, the cost is a + kb where k is the number of digits that has been changed in the counter. For example, from 2999 to 3000 we have a + 4b as 4 digits has been changed and from 999 to 1000, we also have a + 4b similarly. I want to find a potential method that gives amortised cost for insert as "a + 10b/9.
I know that I have to find a potential function that decreases as much as the costliest insert operation. The more 9s at the end, the more costly the operation is what I know. I have tried some potential functions such as "number of 9s in the counter" as well as "Difference between last digit and 0". The answer needed is a fraction so I am certain the potential function involves a ratio of some kind but I cannot see it. Appreciate any guidance for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i 10^{i-1}$ with $d_i \in \{0, \dots, 9\}$ and define $\Phi(n) = \frac{b}{9}\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i$. In other words, $\Phi(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$, scaled by a factor of $\frac{b}{9}$.

Consider now an increment from $n$ to $n+1$ and let $k \ge 1$ be the number of affected digits. Following this increment, $d_k$ becomes $d_{k}+1$ while all $d_i$ with $i<k$ change from $9$ to $0$. Thefore:
$$\Phi(n+1) - \Phi(n) = \frac{b}{9} \bigg( 1  - 9 \cdot(k-1) \bigg) = \frac{b}{9}-(k-1)b,$$

and the amortized cost is:
$$
a+kb + \Phi(n+1)-\Phi(n) = a + kb + \frac{b}{9}  - (k-1)b = a + \frac{10 b}{9}.
$$

Comment: Brilliantly explained Steven! Thanks a lot!